# How to cycle through Global and Normal orientation?

Tags: modeling

Is there any way to toggle between Global and Normal orientation via a hotkey or with an add-on?[image]

Comment: in what context?

Comment: mesh component translation

Comment: If you mean [transform orientations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html) then Alt+Space. There are shortcuts included in the manual

Comment: @Mr Zak It just brings up a menu with options whereas I need to quickly toggle back and forth between exactly Global and Normal orientation, so your solution is a bit of a hassle since I have to do it very often.

Comment: Using Alt+Space is standard way of choosing transform orientations in Blender; though if you really want using shortcuts for certain orientations you can define custom shortcuts in User prefs as is written in the answer below